# problem on vscode on manjaro linux, error MSB4025:

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code

the whole error

> /home/ninjamanthing/C#/projak/HELLP.cs : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> /home/ninjamanthing/C#/projak/HELLP.cs : error MSB4025:

i cant find anything on it online, and i dont know enough about C# to try to solve this problem

i am very new to C#

Comment: update: now it says "The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again." WHAT DOES IT MEAN!?!?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue I think:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

/home/aloisdg/Source/extLauncher/ExtLauncher/ExtLauncher.fsproj : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
/home/aloisdg/Source/extLauncher/ExtLauncher/ExtLauncher.fsproj : error MSB4025: 

Build FAILED.

/home/aloisdg/Source/extLauncher/ExtLauncher/ExtLauncher.fsproj : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
/home/aloisdg/Source/extLauncher/ExtLauncher/ExtLauncher.fsproj : error MSB4025: 
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

In my case, the issue was because I have a not valid fsproj. Look if your csproj is correct. Check your diff if you are using a source manager like git. Then, you can pass it through an xml validator then check it line by line with the doc. Good luck.